# Change php array when user checks a checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, button, checkbox, hyperlink

I have a column that has a button that when pressed, links to a URL set in PHP. I want to add a checkbox next to that button so that if it's checked when a user presses the button, it will take them to an alternate url. The PHP code setting the url:

```
<?php
    $link =  'http://www.example.com'; 
?>
```

I realize that the code needs to be in javascript, which I don't know. I know only a tiny bit of php, so any help would be apprciated.

To clarify: (and of course I know this code will never work)

What I want to do is this:

```
<?php

    If (checkbox is checked) {
        $link =  'http://www.google.com';
    } else {
        $link =  'http://www.example.com';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use Javascript/jQuery for this task.

Comment: I'd advise to not do that but submit the form and treat the checkbox on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jQuery from Google:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then write the redirect function which you call after clicking the button;

```
<script>
function foo() {
  if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
      //redirect to google.com
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
  } else {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
  } 
}
</script>
```

And finaly your button should look like this:

```
<button onclick="foo();" >Your button</button>
```

This code assumes your checkbox has an id "checkbox".

Also, I don't think that what you're trying to do should be done with PHP - so you should learn Javascript/jQuery straight away instead of writing code the way it shouldn't be written.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another way to do what you want to achieve. The value of the checkbox should be sent to a single php script on the server with the rest of the form's fields' values. Then you can use the checkbox's value (boolean) in php and do what you need to do accordingly, possibly requiring external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox value is not sent to server with form submit if it is not checked.
So, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])) {
        $link =  'http://www.google.com';
    }else{
        $link =  'http://www.example.com';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5bdae/

Using jQuery this is fairly simple. You bind a function to the link, this function works out whether the checkbox is checked, if it is it links to one place, otherwise it links to another.

For an HTML structure like this:

```
<input id='myCheckbox' type="checkbox" name="box" value="box" />
<a href='#' id='myLink'>My Link</a>
```

The jQuery would be:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')){
        window.location.href='http://www.example.com';
    } else {
        window.location.href='http://www.ask.com';   
    }
});
```

This could would go outside of the PHP tags, and you would need to [include jQuery](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) in your code.